# Permission Mysql Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: permissions, apache2, mysql, lamp

I have a problem. I install on my ubuntu 18.04.1 lamp server + phpmyadmin. And run existing site (locally). Main page working good. But all another pages return 404. I get this site from windows (Openserver), files and database.
data from apache error_log

```
27.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2018:17:24:43 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11017 "http://cencal.loc/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2018:17:24:45 +0300] "GET /tasks/20171005task197brstj/ HTTP/1.1" 404 517 "http://cencal.loc/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2018:17:25:26 +0300] "GET /tasks/20171005task197brstj/ HTTP/1.1" 404 518 "http://cencal.loc/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2018:17:25:27 +0300] "GET /tasks/20171005task197brstj/ HTTP/1.1" 404 517 "http://cencal.loc/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
```

My site based on /home/user/serv/sitename
I using wordpress for this site and I update peralinks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `.htaccess` file with the following content is created in the document root directory of your website:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also, check if using of `.htaccess` files is allowed in the Apache configuration.

Comment: I think problem isn't i=on wordpress, problem with mysql